# JavaFX MediaPlayer media path

Tags: java, io, javafx, media-player

My problem is that when I compile my program, the video which I'm using as a background is not included in the .jar file. In other words, if another person using the program on a different computer does not have the background video in a specific folder, the program will not run.

When I add images to my buttons, etc... once I build my program, they are included in the `.jar` file and anybody using the program, on any computer, will have access to the images. I pull images by doing this:

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("imagePath.png");
```

I figured that if I try to use the `.getResourceAsStream` method for my `MediaPlayer`, the video will also be included in the compiled `.jar` file. The problem is that my program doesn't work with the following line of code:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myVideo.mp4").toString()));
```

However, it does work perfectly with

```
File file = new File("myVideo.mp4");
String MEDIA_URL = file.toURI().toString();
final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(MEDIA_URL);
```

So, why is `.getResourceAsStream()` not working? Also, do you know of an alternative to package all the needed information in the .jar file when building the program?

Comment: If the video is packaged in the jar file, then the getResourceAsStream() mechanism will work (though I use toExternalForm() instead of toString() on the resource). That's obviously what you want: so this is really a tooling problem: you just need to persuade whatever you are using to generate the jar file (Netbeans? Eclipse?) to include the video.

Comment: @James_D and how do I achieve that in NetBeans? Please explain.

Comment: I'm not a NetBeans user, so I can't give a full answer to that, but for a quick test I just copied a file to the correct place in the hierarchy under "Source Packages" in the NetBeans project (having set the project up as a JavaFX project), then did a build of the project. The file was bundled in the jar file as required.